# Database logic for online shop orders magament

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, logic

I am designing as a project a web store (using PHP Laravel and MySQL FYI) and I am at the part where I have to create the logic behind the production system, which goes like this:

-On my Database,
I have 1 ORDER table where I have all the information regarding the shipping, customer, etc.

- I have another table called ITEM where are listed all the Items in an order (so if an order has 3 items, there will be 3 lines in the ITEM table with a Foreign Key pointing to the ORDER).

Now I'm creating the PRODUCTION DASHBOARD. Right now I'm able to scan the item ID and get the shipment information on the Dashboard. 
After that, for orders with multiple items what I want to do is for the system to tell the user to deposit the item in a numbered box to wait for the rest of the items from the order. That way the user can keep scanning items from other orders and once another item from the ordered stored in X box is produced, he can scan it and the system will then tell him that the other items from the same Order and placed on X box and he can do that until the order is complete.

My question is what would be the best way and logic Database wise (and also Laravel wise if you want to further expand your answer hehe) to implement this BOX system.

I hope my question is clear enough and thank you very much :)

Comment: Why not just have the box number be the order number?

Comment: Because the idea is to have physical numbered boxes in production to deposit items of a incomplete order. 
For example, I scan an item from order number 1234 and since the order is not yet complete (the other items are not ready yet) I put the item in Box Number 3. For the next item of the same order I know that Box Number 3 is already being used to store the order items. Once I scan the last item in the order I go to box number 3 to recover all the items belonging to that order and I ship them

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar system for a project that I was working on. What I did was, was create a database table called temp_orders with a column called items that each item was separated by a line break. Until the order was finalized (100% processed), the order would remain in temp_orders.

Once finalized, it would get deleted from temp_orders and moved over to the orders table. If I needed to check items, I would explode() the data from the items column in temp_orders table using a line break, thus putting them into an array and then using the data however I needed to.

You need to determine when you want to finalize the order. It could be upon credit card payment, or upon user order confirmation, for example.